# How do I send a request to get specific data from server using HttpUrlConection in android?

Tags: php, android

I am a fresher to android. There are lot of examples to get data from server using HttpClient, HttpPost. but unfortunately i couldn't find any option to get specific data from server via HttpUrlConnection.

I want to know,
How to pass data to a PHP file in server from my android app
as well as how to read that data from PHP file

I found a way to resend the queried data to android app from PHP file and read that data from android app using json.

Comment: 'I found a way to resend the queried data to android app from PHP file and read that data from android app using json.'. Well then you are done. What do you need more?

Comment: I want to get specific data,
for an example there is a table called "Person" that has attributes like "name", "age", "city'. then I want to get the persons who are 20 years old or above. so i want to send 20 from my Android app to php script to query that data.
how do i send that 20 from android app, as well as how i read it in my PHP script in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET request:

```
InputStream is = null;
URL url = new URL( "http://my_url/index.php?par1=val1&par2=val2" );
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout( 20000 );       // if you want to set the Read timeout
conn.setConnectTimeout( 30000 );    // if you want to set the Connect timeout
conn.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
conn.setDoInput( true );
conn.connect();
if( conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK )
{
    is = conn.getInputStream();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( is, "UTF-8" );
    char[] buffer = new char[10240];
    int len = reader.read( buffer );
    // ...
}
if( is != null ) is.close();
```

POST request:

```
URL url = new URL( address );
int len = params.getBytes().length;
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setUseCaches( false );
// conn.setDoInput( true );    // input channel needed?
conn.setDoOutput( true );
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ); 
conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8" );
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString( len ) );
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode( len );
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
dos.writeBytes( params );
dos.flush();
dos.close();
conn.disconnect();
```

And of course try / catch the required exceptions.

UPDATE: example Android POST parameter "age":

```
params = "age=20";
```

PHP line to read "age":

```
$age = intval( $_POST['age'] );
```

Comment: thank You for reply this. then how to read this data from PHP script in server?

Comment: @MFaizan: try starting with `var_dump( $_REQUEST );` - then look deeply the PHP [predefined variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) or search in other questions, there are a lot of similar requests

Comment: What is params? Nobody can see which or what data you are sending. For instance there is no 20.

Comment: Params is the string with the parameters, for example: `String params = "par1=val1&par2=val2";` - what is 20?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get data from server

**This is my Android MainActivity**

```
package com.example.mfjaleel.myPackage;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        btn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        new JSONTask().execute("Ur link","parameters");
                    }
                }
        );

    }


   public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String >{
       ProgressDialog loading;
       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           HttpURLConnection connection = null;
           BufferedReader reader = null;

           URL url ;
           try {
               url = new URL(params[0]);
               connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               //connection.connect();
               connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
               connection.setDoInput(true);
               connection.setDoOutput(true);

               HashMap<String,String > data = new HashMap<String, String>();
               data.put("id",params[1]);



               OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
               BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
               writer.write(getPostDataString(data));

               writer.flush();
               writer.close();
               os.close();

               int responseCode=connection.getResponseCode();

              String response = "";
               if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                   reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                   response = reader.readLine();
               }
               else {
                   response="Error Registering";
               }

               return response;


           } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return "MalformedURLException Exception";
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return "IO Exception";
           }
           //return "Error";
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();
           loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
           super.onPostExecute(s);
           loading.dismiss();
           tv.setText(s);
       }

       private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
           StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
           boolean first = true;
           for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
               if (first)
                   first = false;
               else
                   result.append("&");

               result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
               result.append("=");
               result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
           }

           return result.toString();
       }
   }

}
```

**This is my PHP script in Server**

```
function getAll($id){
    $con = new mysqli("localhost","root","password","db_name");
    if($con->connect_error){
        die("Connection Failed ".$con->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * from TABLE_NAME WHERE id = $id";
    $query = $con->query($sql);

    while($r = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $output[] = $r;     
    }

    $con->close();
    return json_encode($output);
}

$x = 2;
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $x = $_POST["id"];
}
$p = getAll($x);
echo $p;
```

*Thank U for helped @mat and @greenapps*